# UX for future timeline

Tags: ux-designer, lean-ux, institutionalizing-ux

The picture below its an screenshot of the layout of cards that are filled with information for future events such as: Concerts, clubs events, celebrations on a specific area, etc

So i need to show the DATE in a very intuitive way for users doesn't need to read every card. So far we think that a divider may be the best BUT it would mess with the layout because the line would make everything align on top.

So if you pay attention to the "San Patrick" event you can see the intentions... yes right now its too subtle but it will better when people write their own event because some will be much larger.

If you guys still don't understand then think on "How the hell do i add dates to Pinterest if Pinterest was about future and no about past post? (where date its important but not as much)"

[image: Timeline]

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. Could you edit the question to include: 1.) A clearly-stated, answerable question, 2.) More detail about the constraints you're working within…like, the cards need to be laid out in a certain direction, certain things are user-generated, etc. 3.) More detail about what solutions you've already tried—and more importantly, *why* you felt like they were inadequate

Comment: It appears you don't want to change your layout to accommodate a user need. Sometimes that's exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid putting dates on the cards all together and have a two axis calendar as your display grid.

So your X axis would be days of the week and your Y axis could be time of day.

```
        Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday
1:00pm   card  |         |
2:00pm         |  card
```

So left to right, the user can quickly see days and top to bottom would be order of events for that given day.

Or just use the X axis columns as days and let the Y axis just stack cards below as space is required. This allows your card height to vary as needed while still giving some semblance of date order.

Answer (score 0):

The text is very small for the recommended 16px+ font size. I would start here. Putting the dates where "beers" is would be okay, but I think you can create focus on the dates within the blue-grey box by creating better hierarchy within you content.

Comment: Hi, its a screenshot this is not real size, and about the dates there then it would look like a cheap website with "Promo-look a like feeling"

Answer (score 0):

I like what @Matthew.Mclarty suggests of having two axis or just the X axis of different days of the week. Another idea would be have it organized like a calendar itself and say if a day has many events, show thumbnails of cards and onclick expand to the detailed view of cards to specific day.

You could organize the cards daily|Weekly|Monthly basis.